# Magento + jQuery toggle click function (IE error)

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, magento

I am running a small jQuery script in products list (list.phtml) page. At present the products are listed one above the other and are defined by categories. A product listing has various snippets of information such as product name, code, price etc. By default Magento includes in the list format (opposed to block listings) a short product description per listing. I have added a simple `onclick` function to show/hide the description. I am fairly new to jQuery and as consequence it may not be written incredibly neatly however it appears to serve its purpose... at least that's what I thought.

In IE however it displays an error once the function is clicked on. My question is, could someone else check this and tell me why this is happening. As always any help is very much appreciated.

Visit http://www.littlekidsbeds.co.uk/special-offers.html all category pages display in the same way at present.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var $j = jQuery.noConflict(); 
    $j(document).ready(function() {     
        $j(".products-list .toggle").hide();
        $j(this).find(".products-list .desc").click(function() {
            $j(this).next(".products-list .toggle").toggle();
            $j(event).stopPropagation();
        });
    });
</script>
```

Error message in internet explorer (IE)

Line: 124
Char: 9
Error: Object doesn't support this proerty or method 
Code: 0
URL: http://www/littlekidsbeds.co.uk/...

Further to the above. debug in firebug error console and the following error comes up: $j(event).stopPropagation is not a function error source line: [Break On This Error] $j(event).stopPropagation();

Anyone that's interested in the solution for this - jQuery toggle function in Magento. I figured out the solution finally which appears to bring back no errors in firebug.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var $j = jQuery.noConflict(); 
    $j(document).ready(function() {     
        $j(".YOURCLASS").hide();
        $j(this).find(".YOURCLASS").click(function() {
            $j(this).next(".YOURCLASS").toggle();
            event.stopPropagation();
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: What error does IE give you when you click?

Comment: Error message in internet explorer (IE)

Line: 124 Char: 9 Error: Object doesn't support this proerty or method Code: 0 URL: ...

Comment: try to put event in your function: function(event)

Comment: it's working well in IE9, I haven't got any error message. Seems to me, your browser cache keep old version of script. Try to clean.

Comment: Error message occurs in IE7... will try cleaning the cache... re: function(event) second function element.. example "$j(this).find(".products-list .desc").click(function(event); {"

Comment: Oğuz Çelikdemir tried to clear cache and unfortunately made no difference.